# Scalamock in asynchronous context

Tags: akka, scalatest, scalamock

I would like to mock some service that i pass to an actor. Then i want to verify that the mocked service is called as it should. Preferably i want to pass a stub, so i can simulate a service behavior for the sake of the test.

However i don't know how i can assert that the stub was called as it should in the main thread.

Is there a way to achieve this ?

I checked the

```
trait AsyncAssertions
```

But it does not seems to solve the issue.

Comment: @MaatDaemon any news on this?

Comment: Check the silent actor in akka actor book, in the testing actor part. I believe it is the other way around to deal with it. They are Actor that are performing side effect or something akin. There is some approach on how to test them. You will work with akka testkit

Comment: The book is akka in action

Comment: thanks, will give a look!